# spark sql encoder for immutable data type

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I've generally used immutable value types when writing java code. Sometimes it's been through libraries (Immutables, AutoValue, Lombok), but mostly just vanilla java classes with:

- all `final` fields
- a constructor with all fields as parameters

(This question is for java 11 and below, given current spark support).

In Spark Sql, data types require an `Encoder`. Using off-the-shelf encoders like `Encoder.bean(MyType.class)`, using such an immutable data type results in "illegal reflective access operation".

I'm curious what the spark sql (dataset) approach is here. Obviously I could relax this and make it a mutable pojo.

---

**Update**

Looking into the code for `Encoders.bean` it really does have to be a classic, mutable POJO. The reflection code looks for appropriate setters. Further (and this is documented) the only supported collection types are `array`, `list` and `map` (not `set`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a misdiagnosis. The immutability of my data type was not causing the reflective access issues. It was a JVM 11+ issue (mostly noted here) https://github.com/renaissance-benchmarks/renaissance/issues/241

By adding the following JVM arguments everything is working correctly:

> --illegal-access=deny --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED